# Computed value with LAG() in UPDATE / SET statement throws error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL statement that is causing me some trouble (I'm very new to tsql).

```
   UPDATE #temp
   SET roe = net_income / LAG(equity, 1) OVER (ORDER BY [year])

   SELECT net_income / ( LAG(equity, 1) OVER (ORDER BY [year]) ) as roe FROM #temp -- this select statement works just fine however.

   SELECT * FROM #temp -- please see picture below for data
```

[image]

I receive the following error: `Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.`

What is causing this? Running the code in a select statement works just fine.

Comment: To use windowed functions in an `UPDATE`, you need to use an updatable CTE.

Comment: How can I append a computed value like I want to a temporary table? A CTE would not be stored in the session after evaluation if I am correct...

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/145612/5203

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to use an updatable CTE here:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT roe,
           net_income / LAG(equity, 1) OVER (ORDER BY [year]) AS NewRoe
    FROM #Temp)
UPDATE CTE
SET roe = NewRoe;
```

*If* `equity` could have a value of `0`, I would also suggest wrapping the `LAG` expression in a `NULLIF`.